# Using ArcGIS API for Timeslider with Google Maps API?

Tags: arcgis-server, google-maps-api, timeslider

Is it possible to use ArcGIS API for a Timeslider with Google maps API?

If this is not possible, then is there some other way I can use a timeslider outside of ArcGIS?

Comment: You cannot just combine these two APIs but as the slider is mostly likely a Dojo element, you could look Into that. Basically any library that has sliders can help you achieve this, but it might require some coding to get it to work with your geodata.

Comment: No use jquery instead http://piotrkrosniak.github.io/